# lumen validation: rule for value not exists in database

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request, lumen

i´m using lumen 5.5 and want to prove that a given value is `required`, `exists in table A` and `does NOT exist in table B`.

while the first two rules can be found in the documentation I´m unable to find a solution for the third.

So this is what I currently use:

```
$rules = [
  'email' => 'required|exists:user,email'
];
```

Something like this is what I want:

```
$rules = [
  'email' => 'required|exists:user,email|not_exists:blocklist,email'
];
```

Someone know a simple validation rule for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$rules = [
  'email' => 'required|exists:users|unique:blocklist'
];
```

Explanation:

- With the [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists) rule we are making it sure that the provided email must exist in your `users` table under the column `email`.
- With the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique) rule we are making it sure that there must not exist a matching email in the `blocklist` table (under the `email` column).

In both cases, I didn't specify a column name because the attribute name is the same than the matching column in the database. If you want to customize it just include it after a `,`. e.g: `required|exists:users,another_column`